# How to solve absolute value inequality?

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

$\frac{|x-B|}{|x|}<C$

I've tried many ways without getting far so I decided not to post my steps.

Can you please explain me how it's done?

Comment: consider three cases:  $x<0$, $0<x<B$, and $x\ge B$

Comment: The inequality is false when $x$ is close to $0$, $B \neq 0$ and $C$ is independent of $x$.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Did you really prove the inequality using those cases?

Comment: @KaboMurphy:  no, it was merely a suggestion, and I concede that I didn't consider $B<0$

Comment: Do you realize that often, when someone _does_ take the time to post their work that "didn't get far", it turns out they were one or two steps away from the solution at some point? Not having done that, you're getting hints at how to start which may be duplicating things you've already tried, rather than getting hints how to finish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$\left|\frac{x-B}{x}\right|<C$$  By the definition of absolute value, this means $$-C< \frac{x-B}{x}<C$$  Now we just have to clear the denominator by multiplying through by $x$.  There are two cases.  When $x>0$ the inequality signs don't change.  When $x<0$ the signs are reversed.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: @ToniMhax The $b$ seems to have disappeared.  Also, you have to consider the signs. $-1 < 2$ but it isn't true that $-1>\frac12.$

Comment: $-c-1<\dfrac{-b}{x}<c-1$ and $1-c<\dfrac{b}{x}<1+c$. Corrected

Answer (score 2):

There is no solution if $C \leq 0.$ (Think about it.)

We must have $x \neq 0.$
With that in mind you get
$\lvert x-B\rvert < C\lvert x\rvert.$

There are then various approaches. One is to split into cases as much as you need in order to proceed, then put it back together.

To find the cases for an inequality with absolute values, one way is to go systematically through the inequality, creating two cases for the first absolute value (the absolute value is either just the expression inside, or the negative of that expression), and within each of those two cases two subcases for the second absolute value (so now you have four cases), and within each of *those* cases two subcases for the third absolute value, and so forth.
In this problem you start with two absolute values (or just one if you recall that $\lvert p\rvert/\lvert q\rvert = \lvert p/q\rvert$), so at worst you have four cases to work out.

Another approach is, since both sides must be positive, you don't lose solutions or introduce any spurious solutions if you square both sides.
This gets rid of the absolute values and now you just need to solve a quadratic inequality.

Answer (score 0):

I mostly agree with J.W. Tanner's idea, except that it is unknown whether B > 0. I recommend a more formal approach as follows:

First of all, it is easiest to interpret |*an expression*| as depending on whether *the expression* is >=0 or < 0 (**two cases**)
rather than making *the expression* = 0 a **third case to consider**.

Thus, since your equation has two occurrences of |*an expression*|, you have to deal with 2x2 = 4 cases.  There are three qualifications to this approach.

1. Sometimes some of the *cases* may be impossible, or may **dovetail** into each other.  For instance the case of x < -5 would dovetail into the case of x < -3, if those two cases showed up (which they don't in your problem).
2. The solution may depend on whether B >= 0.  A formal approach would be for you to give one solution based on the assumption that B >=0, and another solution based on the assumption that B < 0.
3. In your specific problem, you are obviously going to have to look at the special case of x=0 separately, because of the denominator.

Comment: If by "look at the special case separately" you mean "rule that case out immediately," then yes, that's what to do with the case $x=0.$

Comment: @DavidK ..."rule that case out immediately,"... **No**, I mean **more than that**.  Assuming that B>0, because of the denominator, the formal approach would be to create 2x3 = 6 cases, and examine each case separately.  Then, on a case by case basis, you would exclude any of the cases whether the result was **either false or meaningless**, where a result is construed to be meaningless because it involves division by zero.  Your approach, which involves immediately excluding x=0 actually represents **an informal shortcut** to the formal approach.  I advise the formal approach instead.

Comment: If $x = 0$ the left side is undefined. There's nothing "informal" about it. "Formal" is fine, but you don't have to overcomplicate things in order to be formal.

Comment: If I understand your last comment correctly, you propose $6$ subcases when $B>0,$ and presumably at least as many when $B\leq 0,$ so you have at least $12$ cases, each of which you propose to examine one by one. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @DavidK **Yes**.  When the student's *intuition* is shaky, it is best to go slow and careful.  Then, after finding an inequality in each of the 12 cases, the student can consider excluding cases that are *impossible* and **perhaps** looking for an *elegant* way to consolidate the other cases.  Then, the student may consider **re-working the problem from scratch**, based on **intuition developed by the initial approach.**

Comment: The systematic approach that I learned says each absolute value can go one of either two ways, so if you have $n$ absolute values in a question you have $2^n$ cases (at worst). For this problem that's four cases.

Comment: @DavidK Normally, I would agree with you.  But given the denominator, it is best to examine 3 cases (re the denominator), rather than 2: namely x < 0, x= 0, x>0.  By separating x=0 from x>0, your separating out the case that involves division by zero.